# How packet is transmitted over the network?

Tags: networking, packet-capture, packet

I am writing discrete event-driven simulator to measure time between sending datasets over network.

If multiple processes sends `n` packets through network they (packets) will go one after one through link or they will simultaneously share network via tcp/ip protocol?

Comment: You're getting into the fundamentals of networking and multiplexing here. There are as many different answers as there are modes of transportation. [CDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-division_multiple_access), [CSMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-sense_multiple_access), [TDD, FDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications))...

Comment: Sounds like you have A LOT of reading to do before you start writing your 'simulator'...

Comment: @DanielWidrick advices welcome

Comment: Best advice is to study networking concepts from books dedicated to the subject.

Answer (score 1):

On the physical level (and layer), all traffic is sequential. When several applications or processes send data at the same time the transmissions are queued and sent one after the other at the OS's or the driver's discretion. The network stack works as a multiplex for virtually unlimited logical connections over a single network card.

When using bonded/aggregated interfaces or multiple NICs with load balancing the traffic can be somewhat parallel (not for a specific source-destination flow, only for multiple flows).